# In my Spring Boot MVC application, I'm attempting to add error conditions

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I'm trying to delete students from the database based on their student id (sid). The goal is to delete the student whose sid is equal to the sid in the URL and return an HTTP 200 response thats working. NOW If the student to be deleted has associated modules, he/she should not be deleted. Instead, an HTTP status 500 response should be returned with a message indicating the reason the delete could not be performed. If the student to be deleted does not exist, an HTTP 500 response with an appropriate error message should be returned.

The issue seems to be with the mapping of the sid path variable in the `deleteStudentBySid` method of the `StudentController` class. To resolve this issue, I tried updating the `@PathVariable` annotation in the `deleteStudentBySid` method to match the name of the path variable in the URL im trying to run this on POSTMAN. Here are the 3 classes, please help me figure this out if you know how to fix it:

```java
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import com.example.demo.services.StudentService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {
    private final StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{sid}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteStudentBySid(@PathVariable("sid") String sid) {
        studentService.deleteStudentBySid(sid);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import com.example.demo.repository.studentRepo;

@Service
public class StudentService {

    private final studentRepo studentRepository;

    public StudentService(studentRepo studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void deleteStudentBySid(String sid) {
        studentRepository.findBySid(sid).ifPresent(student -> {
            studentRepository.delete(student);
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.demo.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;

@Repository
public interface studentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    List<Student> findAll();
    Optional<Student> findBySid(String sid);
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the actual issue you have? seems like you forgot to add that part.

Answer (score 0):

One little recommendation:
replace  `Optional<Student> findBySid(String sid);`

with  `Optional<Student> getBySid(String sid);`

More details why, you can get here: [The Spring Data JPA findById Anti-Pattern](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-data-jpa-findbyid/)